# What would be the easiest solution to convert table to specific format

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel like this

| ID EW | PARC ID | POW ID | WOJ ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1 | NAMEa1 | NAMEp2 | NAMEw3 |
| 1.1.2 | NAMEa1 | NAMEp2 | NAMEw3 |
| 1.1.3 | NAMEa1 | NAMEp2 | NAMEw3 |
| 1.2.1 | NAMEa4 | NAMEp2 | NAMEw3 |
| 1.2.2 | NAMEa4 | NAMEp2 | NAMEw3 |
| 1.3.3 | NAMEa5 | NAMEp3 | NAMEw3 |

What would be the best way to convert it to format like this :

| WOJ ID NAMEw3 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **POW ID** | NAMEp2 |  |  |
| *PARC ID* | NAMEa1 |  |  |
| ID EW | 1.1.1 | 1.1.2 | 1.1.3 |
| *PARC ID* | NAMEa4 |  |  |
| ID EW | 1.2.1 | 1.2.2 |  |
| **POW ID** | NAMEp3 |  |  |
| *PARC ID* | NAMEa5 |  |  |
| ID EW | 1.3.3 |  |  |

I was trying to do it with pivot table but with no results.

.......................

Comment: Please consult the "Help Center" to learn which type of question you should avoid to ask and please show your own effort.

Comment: Transpose and subtotals :-)